# Why PAC-learnable

Tags: probability, machine-learning

Suppose we have a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ that is non-uniform learnable via sample compelxity function $m_{\text{NUL}}:[0,1]^2 \times \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.
If we define $\mathcal{H}_n=\{h \in \mathcal{H}: m_{\text{NUL}}(0.1,0.1,h) \le n\}$, why is $\mathcal{H}_n$ PAC-learnable?

This argument is used in *proof of theorem 7.2* in this book
http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf

It is stated that, by assuming realizability, using the same learning algorithm $A$, with probability at least $0.9$ over sample $S \sim \mathcal{D}^n$, we have $L_{\mathcal{D}}(A(S)) \le 0.1$.
But I don't see immediately why this is PAC-learnable because we should be able to compress the error below any $\epsilon$ with arbitrarily high probability $1-\delta$. What is the trick?